# iOS Safari: touchstart doesn't fire on dynamically inserted element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, iphone-web-app, touchstart

I'm working on an web app for iOS Safari.
I've got a search input with an autocompletion/suggestions list below it.
With javascript I add the suggestions to the list:

```
document.getElementById('selector_autocomplete').innerHTML
 += '<span ontouchstart="selector_select(' + i + ');">' + name + '</span><br />';
```

Now the problem is that the `ontouchstart` doesn't seem to get fired when touching the element.

I've tested it with `console.log();` etc. But nothing happens.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ontouchstart=""` attribute does not add a listener to the node when inserted into the DOM. Only at the first load of the page.

Using `addEventListener('touchstart', ...);` on the items after inserting them is the solution here.